# ntpq peers output explanation

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I got following output from ntpq command:

```
# ntpq -pn                                                     
 remote           refid            st t when poll reach delay  offset jitter 
================================================================================ 
*192.168.1.1          10.10.4.1     2 u  68y 1024 170   0.198   0.584  0.606
```

What does the `68y` mean in the `when` column? Documentation says it is time since last received packet. Does it mean the last received packet was received 68 years ago? Can I believe that?

```
# ntpq --version 
ntpq 4.2.8p11
```

Comment: 2^31 seconds is 68.1 years. This is also equal to -1 if stored in a unsigned 32-bit integer.  ... assuming I've got the maths right.

Comment: @Kusalananda: good hint, nevertheless -1 is usually 2^32-1 (not 2^31). But yes it might be max signed 32 bit number in seconds. But still - why is that strange number there?

Comment: Yeah, forget about that -1 thing. I obviously got that wrong.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but by best practice you should be pointed to a minimum of three servers so your local server can determine if one of them is out of its mind. It is also best if they are all of the same stratum.

Answer (score 3):

The `reach` value is an octal representation of the results of 8 previous attempts to poll the remote NTP server. The octal value `170` maps to binary value `01111000`, indicating that the last three poll attempts all failed.

The `poll` value indicates the current poll interval: in your case, 1024 seconds is the default maximum value. That would indicate that `ntpd` has been maintaining a connection to the remote time server at 192.168.1.1 for a significant time, and has achieved a pretty good synchronization with it, as evidenced by the pretty good `delay`, `offset` and `jitter` values too. As a result, it has adjusted the `poll` value to the maximum allowed.

As the `reach` value indicated that last three poll attempts all failed, the `poll` value of 1024 means it must be at least 3076 seconds since the last successful poll of the configured remote NTP server.

In the [source code for ntpq subcommands](https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/master-no-authorname/ntpq/ntpq-subs.c), the `when` value is calculated by the [`prettyinterval()`](https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/master-no-authorname/ntpq/ntpq-subs.c#L1459) function. As the name indicates, it takes a length of a time interval as a parameter, and that parameter is calculated by the function [`when()`](https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/master-no-authorname/ntpq/ntpq-subs.c#L1436). It calculates the interval either between the current timestamp and the last receive timestamp, or if the receive timestamp is zero, between the current timestamp and the last reference timestamp.

It seems to me that the only ways `when()` would produce large values would be if either the last receive timestamp has a non-zero but an unexpectedly small value, or if the last receive timestamp is zero *and* the last reference timestamp is non-zero but unexpectedly small.

My wild guess: when the remote NTP server was last reached, it may have been emitting non-sensical NTP timestamps in its responses. Or your local system clock is really insane. With a few rough calculations, either the remote NTP server has been emitting timestamps indicating year 1954 or so, or this system's local idea of time could be somewhere around year 2090.

Comment: +1 but not accepted answer because the main question is still open. The last 3 poll attempts failed because the server 192.168.1.1 was down. It is up again now. The ntpq output contains slightly less 'when' value `63y 1024 377`. Both machines (server and client) have correct and precise system clock. They are in different timezones but I think it is irrelevant.

Comment: ntpd 4.2.8p11 is quite old and has several known low- and medium-grade security bugs. Hopefully you have a version that is maintained by your distribution and has the fixes backported. The strange values might be a side effect of someone or something trying to attack your ntpd - you'll have to decide if that's a realistic possibility in your network environment or not. You might want to consider switching from classic `ntpd` to `chronyd` - I've understood ntpd might be starting to suffer a bit from the age of its codebase. You're correct in that timezone should not be relevant for NTP at all.

Comment: You might want to run something like `tcpdump -s0 -i any -Knpvv -w ntp-capture.pcap udp port 123` for a few hours or days, and then take a look at the results with Wireshark to see if there are incoming (maybe spoofed?) NTP packets with wildly inaccurate NTP timestamps or other strangeness.

Comment: The tcpdump does not discover any abnormal values so far and the ntpq output remains strange. The client is an embedded linux and it is not easy to update packages there. I will try to build a newer ntpq and check with it.